# PyCharm issue after moving project folder: Cannot setup python SDK at Python 2.7 (/Library/Framework...)

Tags: python, pycharm, project

I am running PyCharm Community 2018.2 on macOS 10.13.6

II know that macOS comes with Python preinstalled. I believe that when you go to `https://www.python.org/`, download the `python-3.7.0-macosx10.9.pkg` file, and run it to install Python, it installs Python, a second time, but in a different location.

I believe that the location of the pre-installed macOS Python is: `usr/bin/python`. I know this by opening Terminal and typing `which python`. I also believe that if I want to see the location that the .pkg file installed Python, I'd need to type in: `which python3`. When I do that, I get: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`.

I created a new Python project a few weeks back that just contains one .py file, and that's it. I did some file clean-up to get better organized, and I moved that project folder into a new folder. Today when I opened PyCharm, I went to **Open:** and I searched for and selected that **project folder** and clicked **Ok**. It loaded, and I could see my python code in the .py file. The 'run' option was grayed out, and I saw the warning message: `Invalid python interpreter selected for the project.  ---  Configure Python interpreter`. 
I clicked to configure the Python interpreter. I had done this once before, but I did not understand it very well then, and I still do not. I see that I can click the sprocket at the end of the line labeled **Project interpreter**, and select "**Add...**"

Then I see two main options:

- New Environment
- Existing Environment

At this point, I just get really confused.

- I am in the configuration of the "**Project** Interpreter."
- Under New Environment there is an option for a "**Base** Interpreter."
- Under Existing Environment, there is also a field that is just
  labeled "**interpreter**."
- To the left there is the option of **System Interpreter:** and when I
  select it, I see `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

It seems like no matter where I try to find the correct interpreter, I get the same error message: 
Cannot setup a python SDK at Python 2.7 (Project_Folder)
(/Library/Framework.../venv/Scripts/python.exe)

If I select "Existing environment" and navigate to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python`... I get the error.

If I select "Existing environment" and navigate to `/usr/bin/python`... it seems to resolve the issue, and I can run the .py file's code again. But is that not the wrong installation of Python? Is that not using the interpreter that came with macOS? When I go to PyCharm > Preferences, the Project Interpreter is now showing as: `Python 2.7 usr/bin/python.` That seems incorrect to me.

Comment: Does https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html help (1st in google on "pycharm select python environment under macos")?

Comment: Please add some screenshots to illustrate the dialogs(?) you're talking about. The explanation is nothing similar to the linked article or what I see in Windows so I've no idea what you're talking about and how you got there.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `.idea` folder

For New Environment:

- Select the new Virtualenv folder location and it must be empty
- Select the installed pythone.exe location in Base Interpreter

For Existing Environment:

- Select the existing Virtualenv folder location and delete it's contents
- Select the installed pythone.exe location in Base Interpreter

It's worked for me.

Good details: [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)